# Magnetic field on axis of solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields

So first I'd like to say that I *have* asked similar questions to this one. However, all the answers involve a level of calculus that I do not yet know. (Still on limits, going to spend the rest of summer break trying to learn calculus.) That said, I have a project that I'd like to do some force calculations for. For that, I need to know how to find the magnetic field strength in T, or G.

I found an equation that would fit my needs but it is for a current loop, not a solenoid.

$$B_z=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{2\pi R^2I}{(z^2+R^2)^{3/2}}$$

Simplifying a solenoid to a collection of current loops, could I calculate the field from every loop in a solenoid and average them? (Yes, I realize this promises to be extremely inefficient and tedious to work out. And also, yes. I see the value of calculus. )

I mean, would that give me an accurate value? Or would that just be a lot of hard work for nothing?

*Edit: To clarify, I was wondering if I could treat each turn in a solenoid as a separate current loop and then average the fields.

Comment: What do you mean by "collection of current loops"?  Are they stacked one _directly_ coincidental with each other (i.e. just many loops "in one loop") or are they stacked vertically as to make a "tube" or is it something else?  The magnetic field inside of an infinite, tubular, solenoid is pretty well known and it's easy to compute "without calculus" (using Ampere's Law which is similar to Gauss's Law for electrostatics).

Comment: @Jared It's not inside the solenoid that I'm worried about. I'm trying to find the field strength at a given point distance $z$ from the solenoid along the axis of the solenoid. Like this, but for a solenoid. And when I said a collection, that's what I meant. Multiple loops side-by-side/on top of eachother. Each would have a slightly different distance from the point of interest, a different loop radius, or both. Basically, I'd like to know if I can treat each turn in a solenoid as a separate current loop and average the field produced.